# Why is type_info declared outside namespace std?

Tags: c++, stl, windows-ce, rtti

I'm using VS2005 and the MS implementation of STL. However, the class type_info in  is declared outside of "namespace std". This creates some problems for third party libs that excepts to find a std::type_info. Why is this so, and is there any workaround? Here is a sample from the beginning of typeinfo:

```
class type_info {
...
};


_STD_BEGIN // = namespace std  {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's interesting - the standard does say that (17.4.1.1. Library contents)

> All library entities except  macros, operator new and operator delete are defined within the namespace std or namespaces nested within namespace std.

And clearly says that (5.2.8 Type identification)

> The result of a typeid expression is an lvalue of static type const std::type_info (18.5.1) and dynamic type const std::type_info or const name where name is an implementation-defined class derived from std::type_info which preserves the behavior described in 18.5.1.

Ans, of course, the descriptin of header `<typeinfo?>` indicate the it should be in namespace `std` (18.5 Type identification):

> Header `<typeinfo>` synopsis
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>     class type_info;
>     class bad_cast;
>     class bad_typeid;
> }
> ```

So `type_info` should be in the `std` namespace (and not outside of it).  I guess that either this is a bug or there's some large set of code (or small set of important code) that needs it outside of the `std` namespace. I'd have thought they'd use some preprocessor magic to make it so you could force it to be in the `std` namespace if desired (or the other way around - make it in `std` by default and allow a macro or something to force it to the global namespace).

However, one additional wrinkle for `type_info` is that it's the result of the `typeid` operator (more precisely, something derived from `type_info` is the result), so there's probably a tight dependency on what the compiler does for the `typeid` operator that the library  needs to be in line with. So the fact that `type_info` isn't in namespace `std` is possibly due to what the compiler does with `typeid` expressions, and the library writers probably have little direct control over that (and I'd guess that's one reason why there's no preprocssor workaround for the problem). Someone who knows a lot more about how compilers work than I do would have to explain this better (or take it beyond speculation).

But I think you'll have to ask someone at Microsoft (or PJ Plauger/Dinkumware) for a real answer to "why".

Comment: OK I found a comment in the typeinfo file. Parafracing, it said "type_info not included in std namespace as RTTI compilers often have an own imlpementation". I solved it by simply moving it into std, against the recommendation in the comment.

Comment: Could you give a little more info on that comment's location and/or the compiler version for the `<typeinfo>` header you saw it in?

Comment: Just in the beginning of the file, under all includes and a pragma call. The file is for wince 6, and probably came either with Platform Builder or with a pre-built SDK sometime long ago. It is copyright Microsoft. Here is the full comment:

// Return type from typeid operator, according to the standard
// this should really be in namespace std, but the compiler
// has built-in knowledge about this class.  Do not modify
// anything here without checking the layout of RTTI information
// generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

With the `using` declaration, actually, there *is* a `std::type_info`. There might be scenarios where the fact that it isn't defined inside of `std` might be a problem, but I'd wonder if you have ran into one of them.

What's your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I copied from the wrong <typeinfo> class. The one I was using was actually for Windows CE (also by MS), and it lacks the using directive. Is this a bug in that specific version of STL?

Comment: If the standard defines a class as belonging in `std`, then it should be defined as such or ADL (Koenig lookup) may break.

Answer (score 0):

Because Visual Studio does all sorts of tricks to allow for legacy code to work.  IIRC, the Standard only states that `type_info` exist within the `std` namespace.  It does not mandate that it not exist within the global namespace - that is really an implementation decision.

*Caveat Emptor:* I haven't verified this in the Standard.

Comment: Actually, the reason why the standard reserves the underscore prefix for the implementation is because implementors can't just claim ordinary names. `::_typeinfo` would be allowed.